# Jenkins GIT connectivity issue

Tags: git, jenkins

I am recieving this error upon specifying the repository path "ssh://Administrator@WS-GIT/GitCentralRepository/Development" in my Jenkins job.

```
"Failed to connect to repository : Command "ls-remote -h ssh://Administrator@WS-GIT/GitCentralRepository/Development HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,keyboard-interactive)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."
```

I am able to clone this project from GITExtensions client upon specifying this same repositiry path. I am running Jenkins as a windows service on windows 7. Please help

Comment: Seems to be an authentication issue. Did you configure Jenkins to have proper credentials to clone from that repo?

Comment: I am using key public key based authentication and I have tried generating keys both with and without passphrase through putty. Please note that I am able to clone from the repository through a GIT client program GIT Extensions using the same repository URL. The client program only asks me the SSH key location and when I provides it it loads the authentication agent program in the background and gets connected to the repository

Comment: I understand that you can clone without a problem. My questions was if Jenkins itself has access to the credentials. I don't know how your Jenkins is configured, but if it's running in a different user, then it will have no access to the SSH key in your account. See this page for more info: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

Comment: Jenkins is running under a domain user account on windows. The .ssh folder is located in the c:\users\username folder of that user and the environment variable HOME is set to the c:\users\username folder. I am also able to run the ls-remote command to the same repository URL from the command prompt which narrows down the problem at hand to jenkins only i guess. I am new to configuration world by the way kindly help me resolvimg this issue

Comment: I'm also having this situation at Jenkins v1.532.1. 
Jenkins master service is running on a Linux and the master of the job (where it fails) is a Windows that has a Jenkins slave service configured to log on with the same user account that works ok when running directly on the PC.

Comment: also not a DNS issue as I do a ping before the git clone that works ok!

Answer (score 0):

I reached this page basically having the same problem, I could successfully run 'git ls-remote ' with the user from the jenkins host, but I could not use it from the Jenkins credentials plugins.

What I had wrongly configured was a silly thing, the credential plugins needed the **private** key not the **public** key.

My Jenkins and gerrit server are under linux but it should make no difference for this issue.

Just in case someone reach this page with a similar issue. 
My scenario was that I wanted to configure a **Non-interactive user** (no passw) to clone a particular repo from gerrit into Jenkins.

If that is your case make sure that

1) create a non-interactive group in jenkins and add your non-interactive user to it
i.e user jenkins, first generate the ssh keys (providing empty pass)

> ssh-keygen-t rsa

then create the user in gerrit andd add it to the Non-Interactive User group

> cat ~jenkis/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -p 29418 your.gerrit.instance.com gerrit create-account --group "'Non-Interactive Users'" --ssh-key - jenkins

2) make sure that the project that you are trying to clone has read access granted for the Non-interactive group (you can do that in the gerrit webUI)

Note: if by chance you change the ssh key directly in the gerrit database (as I did trying to troubleshoot this issue) you'll need to flush gerrit ssh cache

> ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit flush-caches --cache sshkeys

3) make sure you provide the contents of the private key (.ssh/id_rsa) generated in step 2 in the Jenkins credential plugin

4) on your Jenkins job use an url like the following

> ssh://jenkins@your.gerrit.instance.com:29418/yourRepoName

Hope this help someone else

Fede

Check this post it might also help http://toastedbits.com/post/26#integration